# Coming back to the USA on an ESTA VWP after J1 grace period ends

Tags: usa, visa, esta

I am a UK citizen who is in the grace period of my J1 visa. I want to get an ESTA via the VWP for tourism.

From what I understand I can go to Mexico/Canada through the land border and return on an ESTA. However, I'm worried that I might have my request refused, or that I have to wait until the end of my grace period to return.

Also, would I be able to drive my US-registered car back in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific legal problem with doing this. Your grace period ends as soon as you leave the US - there is no need to wait out the 30 days. Note that ESTA [doesn't apply](https://help.cbp.gov/s/article/Article-1132) when driving---you'll simply complete I-94W instead.

Whether the officers will admit you as a tourist, particularly with your US-registered car, is a question nobody can answer with certainty. It's always safest to have a back-up plan just in case you're unable to enter the US due to a surprise denial, new pandemic rules, etc.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your advice. I'm trying to maximise my chances of getting back in. I've got proof of travel insurance, an outbound flight home, job applications out of the country.

Comment: @prayner Do you have a simple answer to "What are you going to do with your car?"